# Nullpointer exception with WalAutoArchiveAfterInactivity

Tags: ignite

I set WalAutoArchiveAfterInactivity to 60 milliseconds, I got NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
 org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.closeBufAndRollover(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:896) at 
 org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.checkWalRolloverRequiredDuringInactivityPeriod(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:784) at 
 org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.access$700(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:158) at 
 org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$7.onTimeout(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:747) at 
 org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.timeout.GridTimeoutProcessor$TimeoutWorker.body(GridTimeoutProcessor.java:234) at 
 org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120) at 
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've filed an issue in the [Apache Ignite Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14130). It looks like there's a race in the WAL rollover procedure. It's visible only with relatively small values for `walAutoArchiveAfterInactivity`. Anyway I can't even imagine a load profile that could benefit from the property being set to 60ms. To be honest I don't think that you really need it.